GLM Reference and Introudction to study my self
I am a third-year statistics student. I have a course in Generalized Linear Models. Unfortunately, the course is taught in French, which is not my primary language, and I am facing some difficulties in understanding the material, even when reading the lecture notes (which are also in French).
Is there any good reference that serves as a solid introduction to GLMs with some examples and derivations?

If it is not, then we have references in an old thread too: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/94371/362671. Check if that answers your query.
